# Rails has_many :through saving additional fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to find a graceful way of saving an additional field called description on the Appointment model (below). My models are setup like this:

```
class Physician < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :appointments
  has_many :patients, through: :appointments
end

class Appointment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :physician
  belongs_to :patient
end

class Patients < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :appointments
  has_many :physicians, through: :appointments
  attr_accessible :name
end
```

In my view I have checkboxes setup to save the data for the join table but I want to slide in an additional "description" field to be saved with the join. Below is what is in my view:

```
<div class="field">
  <fieldset>
  <legend>Patients</legend>
  <% @patients.each_slice(2) do |slice| %>
    <div class='row'>
      <% slice.each do |patient| %>
        <div class='span3'>
          <%= label_tag "physician_patient_ids_#{patient.id}" do %>
            <%= check_box_tag 'physician[patient_ids][]', patient.id,
                              @physician.patients.include?(patient),
                              { id: "physician_patient_ids_#{patient.id}" } %>
            <%= patient.name %>
          <% end %>
          <!-- need to add in description here somehow -->
        </div>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
  </fieldset>
</div>
```

Comment: Does the Patients Model not miss the has_many association?

Comment: Yeah, that was a mess up on my part. The relationships are there, I'll edit it to reflect that.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `accepts_nested_attributes_for` to update the association attributes.

In Model:

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :appointments, :allow_destroy => true
```

In View:

```
<%= f.fields_for :appointments do |apt| %>
  <%= apt.object.patient.name %>
  <%= apt.text_field :description %>
<% end %>
```

Refer http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html

Comment: Don't forget you'll also need to add the necessary params to strong_params in your controller